# WPML - Call to undefined function in social.png?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wpml

from one day to another i receive the below listed error when I open my webpage. The plugin which causes the error is WPML. The only thing I have changed in the past days was the password for the ftp account, but this can't be important for the plugin, can it?

The error message I got is:

> [Mon Oct 27 21:07:21 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] PHP Fatal
>   error:  Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in
>   /is/htdocs/wp156435_TXGERPLQ0D/www/studio/wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/images/social.png(1)
>   : eval()'d code(1) : eval()'d code on line 1

Does anybody know how I can fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`social.png` is php virus script which have been seen in many wordpress plugins .

go to your theme functions.php file and find `require_once("social.png");` OR `include_once("social.png");`
and remove it .

the error you are getting will be removed.

the virus inclusion code in your functions.php probably looks like this

```
if(!defined("WP_OPTION_KEY")) {
   require_once("social.png");
}
```

remove these lines and delete social.png from the directory . if you will not remove this the virus writer might can get access to your files / database

Comment: Thanks Azi. Do you know what the social.png is doing exactly? Why did the site worked yesterday fine and today the error occurs?

Comment: it might be like shell virus .. read about shell scripts here is an article about r57 http://thehackerblog.com/hacking-script-kiddies-r57-gen-tr-shells-are-backdoored-in-a-way-you-probably-wouldnt-guess/#more-447

Comment: I deleted the plugin folder. Am i safe with that? Or can do i have to check anything else?